# how to change another form name in button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows form application ...
I have two forms ..
   1->frm master
    2->frm shifting

i have a OK button in frm shifting..while i cliking the button i want o change the name of `frmmaster`

frmmaster is the my parent form

so i given code in Ok button event like thise

```
frmmaster.Text="NewName"
```

but this is not working..  while coming to this line am getting error:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: sir,,in ok button click i just given code like this..

Comment: are you creating bew instance of first form

Comment: this.MdiParent.Text="blabla"

Comment: while giving this getting error.

Comment: obviously `frm shifting` is not a `MdiChild` of `frm master` so the `MdiParent` property is `null`.

Comment: frmshifting is the child form of frmmaster...

Comment: Ahh ok ok, listen what you have to do is to create a static string property in frmmaster and you will reach it by child form, so when you click button you have to change that property value but when that property changed form's text has to change too, so you will implement and use INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
So start to google how to do it ;)

Comment: what i have to google? please give some more idea?

Comment: i will check...and let u know

Comment: you will use like; f.text. so forget about textbox

Comment: sir in my case frmmaster is parent form and frmshifting is child form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this on your child form's click event:

```
Form form = Application.OpenForms["frmmaster"];
form.Text="lol";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((your frmName)this.MdiParent).Text = "SomeText":
```

like

```
((frmMaster)this.MdiParent).Text = "SomeText"
```

or

Make sure when you create your child form you assign an MDI parent to it.

```
//Open form in frmMaster
frmShifter.MdiParent = this;
```

Comment: where i have to give this code:frmShifter.MdiParent = this;

Comment: oke sir i given this code(frmShifter.MdiParent = this) in frmmaster..and i given this code(frmMaster frm = this.MdiParent as frmMaster;
frm.Text = "SomeText";)in ok button.but still getting same error.

Comment: Yea probably because you are trying to set the text before the MDIParent was assigned to the childform. I assume you try to assign a text in the constructor of the child form. As you first initialize a new instance of your form `frmShifter = new frmShifter()` , the MDIParent is not known there. You can 1. give the MdiParentForm with the constructor of your new form `new frmShifter(this)` and then change the text value or 2. Make a method in the shifter form so you can call the method (with code above) after you assigned the MDI form to your childform.